# How make a diamond text pattern in python 3.5 using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

As stated in the title, I am looking to make a diamond text pattern using python 3.5, but I am a little stuck on how to get the shape working correctly.

Desired output:

```
                   S
                  SAS
                 SAMAS
                SAMPMAS
               SAMPLPMAS
              SAMPLELPMAS
               SAMPLPMAS
                SAMPMAS
                 SAMAS
                  SAS
                   S
```

Code:

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length):
    for j in range(length-i-1):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    for k in range (i-1, -1, -1):
        print (word[k], end="")
    print()
for l in range (1,length):
    for j in range(l) :
        print(' ', end="")
    for m in range (0,length-l-1):
        print(word[m], end ="")
    for n in range (length-l-1,-1,-1):
        print(word[n], end="")
```

Current output:

```
      f
     fof
    fooof
   fooboof
  foobaboof
 foobaraboof
  foobaboof  fooboof   fooof    fof     f
```

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question. If you feel that it would be useful for others to see your variation on Chris Mueller's solution, feel free to add it as an additional answer using the box at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import itertools
l = len(word)
for j in itertools.chain(range(l), reversed(range(l-1))):
    print(word[0:j].rjust(l) + word[j::-1])
```

which gives the output you are looking for.  This uses the `rjust` string method to properly pad the space before the shortened words and uses extended slicing to get the reversed portions of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

You almost have solved it yourself, the only thing missing are **spaces in front of each line**. Now the first line has *n-1* spaces in front, with *n* the length of the string, the second line has *n-2* spaces in front and so on until we reach the middle. The middle line should contain no spaces in front.

After we reached the middle we increment the number of heading spaces one at a time again.

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length):
    for j in range(length-i-1):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    for k in range (i-1, -1, -1):
        print (word[k], end="")
    print()
for l in range (length, 0, -1):
    for j in range(length-l+1):
        print(' ', end="")
    for m in range (l-1, 0, -1):
        print(word[m], end ="")
    for n in range (0, i-1):
        print(word[n], end="")
    print()
```

This is unfortunately not the only problem in your code. When you test it, you will obtain a diamond like:

```
     f
    fof
   fooof
  fooboof
 foobaboof
foobaraboof
 raboofoob
  aboofoob
   boofoob
    oofoob
     ofoob
      foob
```

```
word=input("Enter characters: ")
length=len(word)
for i in range (0, length):
    for j in range(length-i-1):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    for k in range (i-1, -1, -1):
        print (word[k], end="")
    print()
for l in range (1,length):
    for j in range(l) :
        print(' ', end="")
    for m in range (0,length-l-1):
        print(word[m], end ="")
    for n in range (length-l-1,-1,-1):
        print(word[n], end="")
    print()
```

This prints:

```
     f
    fof
   fooof
  fooboof
 foobaboof
foobaraboof
 foobaboof
  fooboof
   fooof
    fof
     f
```

Comment: @BenS: I've tested it locally with `foobar` as a string. Can you update your question with the output you obtain?

Comment: @BenS: well spotted error, I did not fully copy-paste the fragment; the last line was missing. Now it should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing padding at the beginning of each line equal to `length - i - 1` or `length - l - 1` spaces.

```
def print_row(i, l):
    print(" " * (l - i - 1), end="")
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        print(word[j], end="")
    for k in range(i-1, -1, -1):
        print(word[k], end="")
    print()

for i in range(0, length):
    print_row(i, length)
for l in range(length, -1, -1):
    print_row(l, length)
```

**Edit:** Simplified loops

Comment: No need for extra loops to print a repeated string of spaces. :D

Comment: The program still is not correct, the lower part of the diamond does not print the correct characters.

Comment: Haha, cause I copy pasted OP's code. I just noticed that the letter you choose inside the second for loop is off, and your loop is cutting short by 1 iteration.

Comment: I've fixed the error and updated my answer, everything should work now.

Comment: To make the case simpler, we see that the row printing can be extracted since the function is the same, just the order is different; hence the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to print out the whitespace. Think of it like a rectangle rather than a diamond.

To get you started:

```
for i in range (0, length):
  for x in range(0, length-i):
    print(" ", end="")
  for j in range(0, i+1):
    print(word[j], end="")
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works for this problem and is pretty simple:

```
def diamond():
    word = input("Enter characters : ")
    space_length = len(word)
    for i in range(len(word)):
        space_length -= 1
        for k in range(space_length, 0, -1):
            print(" ", end="")
        sliced = word[0:i+1]
        for j in sliced:
            print(j, end="")
        for j in range(0, i):
            print(sliced[len(sliced)-j-2], end="")
        print()
    space_length = 0
    for i in range(len(word), 0, -1):
        space_length += 1
        for k in range(space_length):
            print(" ", end="")
        sliced = word[0:i-1]
        for j in sliced:
            print(j, end="")
        for j in range(len(sliced) - 2, -1, -1):
            print(sliced[j], end="")
        print()
```

Sample output: Enter characters : foobar

```
      f
     fof
    fooof
   fooboof
  foobaboof
 foobaraboof
  foobaboof
   fooboof
    fooof
     fof
      f
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and centered string padding, looping though the generated list and slicing the string to create the diamond as follows:

```
# concatenated list comprehensions
# form 0 to 11 to 0 in steps of 2
diamondlist = [i for i in range(1,12,2)] + [i for i in range(9,0,-2)]

# string to print in diamond shape
text = 'SAMPLETEXTS'

# loop through list using fomat to centre string
# as i incr/decr string is sliced
# y is length of text
for i in diamondlist:
    y = len(text)
    print('{:^{}s}'.format(text[:i], y))
```

**Output:**

```
     S     
    SAM    
   SAMPL   
  SAMPLET  
 SAMPLETEX 
SAMPLETEXTS
 SAMPLETEX 
  SAMPLET  
   SAMPL   
    SAM    
     S
```

**Note:**

This will only work for diamonds starting from 1, but with not too much work you could turn it into a function taking a string a and a diamond width as an argument.